# How to case over command line args in Node.js

Tags: node.js

New to nodejs so please can someone please let me know what is the best way to parse command line args. For example if the program accepts multiple options with short and long forms (s or --silent) and I want to case over them to call specific actions. Any npm packages that I can use to parse the command line options?

Can I use process.argv and case over it?

```
switch (opt) {
   case 's' || 'silent': 
         ...
         break;
   case 'a' || 'action':
         ...
         break;

};
```

Comment: Checkout [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs)

Comment: Of course you can do it yourself by parsing `process.argv`,but there are some good libraries that can help you with that: [minimist](https://github.com/substack/minimist) or [yarg](http://yargs.js.org) could be a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of `npm` packages that do exactly what you are looking for. I have found [commander](https://github.com/tj/commander.js/) to have the best UX for me.

You can also process the arguments yourself as you said, but I would recommend against repeating work that has already been done and using an `npm` package for it (unless your use case is extremely simple).

Other solid options:
- [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs)
- [command-line-args](https://www.npmjs.com/package/command-line-args)
- [minimist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimist)